# SQL QUERY format correction

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have advanced search in my matrimony college project.
I had following query as a result:

```
select * 
from tbl_FreeUserProfile 
where Gender='Male' and Age>= '18' 
  and Age<= '40'    and heightf<='182' 
  and heightf>='152' and MaritalStatus='Never Married' 
  and MotherTongue = 'xyz' or 'Gujarati' or 'Urdu' or 'Hindi'"
```

But when I execute the query it shows the following error:

> > An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'or'

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the format of the sql query?

My coding is like this

```
protected void ImageButton11_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
  {

  string sql = "select * from tbl_FreeUserProfile where Gender='" + RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text + "' and Age>= '" + DropDownList25.SelectedItem.Text + "' and Age<= '" + DropDownList26.SelectedItem.Text + "' and heightf<='" + TextBox23.Text + "' and heightf>='" + TextBox22.Text + "' and MaritalStatus='" + DropDownList35.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

  if (ListBox2.Items.Count >= 0)
    {
        sql = sql + " and MotherTongue = 'xyz'";

        for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {                
              string mt = ListBox2.Items[i].ToString();
              sql = sql + " or '" + mt + "'";              
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, using

```
AND (MotherTongue = 'xyz' OR MotherTongue = 'abc' ...)
```

changing your code to

```
if (ListBox2.Items.Count >= 0)
{
    sql = sql + " and ( MotherTongue = 'xyz'";

    for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {                
          string mt = ListBox2.Items[i].ToString();
          sql = sql + " or MotherTongue = '" + mt + "'";              
    }

    sql = sql + ")"
}
```

or

```
AND MotherTongue IN ('xyz', 'abc', ...)
```

changing your code to

```
if (ListBox2.Items.Count >= 0)
{
    sql = sql + " and MotherTongue IN (" + 
          string.Join(",", ListBox2.Items[i].Select(i => i.ToString())) + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted to do something like

```
and MotherTongue IN ('xyz', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Hindi')
```

If you want to use `or` you'll have to specify the field name each time.

Comment: i have edited my que and add the coding i am using, if you can have look at it.

Comment: See Phil's answer (I like the bottom one that uses `string.Join`).

Answer (score 0):

Currently the query being executed ends with:

```
and MotherTongue = 'xyz' or 'Gujarati' or 'Urdu'... so on.
```

The actual query should be:

```
and MotherTongue = 'xyz' or MotherTongue =  'Gujarati' or MotherTongue = 'Urdu'
```

The best way to query multiple languages would be as C.Evenhuis has mentioned i.e. use:

```
and MotherTongue IN ('xyz', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Hindi').
```